# Setting up an optimization solver on top of a neural network model

Tags: python, neural-network, solver

I have a trained neural network model developed using the Keras framework in a Jupyter notebook. It is a regression problem, where I am trying to predict an output variable using some 14 input variables or features.
As a next step, I would like to minimize my output and want to determine what configuration/values these 14 inputs would take to get to the minimal value of the output.

So, essentially, I would like to pass the trained model object as my objective function in a  solver, and also a bunch of constraints on the input variables to optimize/minimize the objective.
What is the best Python solver that can help me get there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

So you already have your trained model, which we can think of as `f(x) = y`.

The standard SciPy method to minimize this is appropriately named [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).

To use it, you just need to adapt your `f(x) = y` function to fit the API that SciPy uses. That is, the first function argument is the list of `params` to optimize over. The second argument is optional, and can contain any `args` that are fixed for the entire optimization (i.e. your trained model).

```py
def score_trained_model(params, args):
    # Get the model from the fixed args.
    model = args[0]

    # Run the model on the params, return the output.
    return model_predict(model, params)
```

With this, plus an initial guess, you can use the `minimize` function now:

```py
# Nelder-Mead is my go-to to start with.
# But it doesn't take advantage of the gradient.
# Something that does, e.g. BGFS, may perform better for your case.
method = 'Nelder-Mead'

# All zeros is fine, but improving this initial guess can help.
guess_params = [0]*14

# Given a trained model, optimize the inputs to minimize the output.
optim_params = scipy.optimize.minimize(
    score_trained_model,
    guess_params,
    args=(trained_model,),
    method=method,
)
```

It is possible to supply constraints and bounds to some of the optimization methods. For Nelder-Mead that is not supported, but you can just return a very large error when constraints are violated.

---

**Older answer.**

OP wants to optimize the inputs, `x`, not the hyperparameters.

It sounds like you want to do hyperparameter optimization. My Python library of choice is `hyperopt`: https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt

Given that you already have some training and scoring code, for example:

```py
def train_and_score(args):
    # Unpack args and train your model.
    model = make_model(**args)
    trained = train_model(model, **args)

    # Return the output you want to minimize.
    return score_model(trained)
```

You can easily use `hyperopt` to tune parameters like the learning rate, dropout, or choice of activations:

```py
from hyperopt import fmin, hp, tpe, space_eval

space = {
    'lr': hp.loguniform('lr', np.log(0.01), np.log(0.5)),
    'dropout': hp.uniform('dropout', 0, 1),
    'activation': hp.choice('activation', ['relu', 'sigmoid']),
}

# Minimize the training score over the space.
trials = Trials()
best = fmin(train_and_score, space, trials=trials, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=100)

# Print details about the best results and hyperparameters.
print(best)
print(space_eval(space, best))
```

There are also libraries that will help you directly integrate this with Keras. A popular choice is `hyperas`: https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas

Comment: Thanks for that answer. But I have already tuned hyperparameters (learning rate, beta1, beta2 for Adam optimizer etc.) and obtained my NN model, say y=f(x). Now I want to pass this f(x) as my objective function in a solver, and impose some constraints with regards to my x's, and solve for the minimun value of f(x), and get the corresponding x's. I have looked at different Optimization libraries in Python like scipy,CVXPY, Pyomo etc. My only struggle is how to pass the NN model as a function into the solver as the objective function

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I have updated my answer to address your intended case, but left the old answer in case it's still useful to others.